# Instantiating an interface in java

Tags: java, interface

My understanding is that an interface cannot be instantiated directly, unless you define an anonymous inner class implementing that interface. But much to my surprise and confusion I see some code which seems to instantiate an interface. 
Here is the code:

```
public final class SqlProviders
{
  private static boolean installed_;

   private static ThreadLocal<SqlAggregateProvider> fortaskInfo_
     = new ThreadLocal<TaskInfoProvider>();
}

 public interface TaskInfoProvider
 {
 int getTaskIndex();

 int getTaskCount();

 long getSessionId();

 long getStatementId();

 long getFunctionInstanceId();

 boolean isTaskInfoAvailable();

 void setTaskInfoAvailable(boolean available);
 }
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Where do you think the interface is instantiated in that code?

Comment: This instantiates an object of type `ThreadLocal` with the generic type parameter `TaskInfoProvider`; nowhere does it instantiate `TaskInfoProvider`. More information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Does this even compile? I would expect the compile error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ThreadLocal<TaskInfoProvider> to ThreadLocal<SqlAggregateProvider>`

Answer (score 1):

The code is not instantiating the `TaskInfoProvider` interface.  It is instantiating the generic class `ThreadLocal` ... with the interface as the classes generic type parameter.  No (hypothetical) instance of `TaskInfoProvider` is being created in the process ....

Obviously, in order to "set the value" of the thread local, you would need an instance of some class that implements the `TaskInfoProvider` interface.  But that's not what is happening in this code snippet.